# Integrate ddmegamenu in drupal menu

Tags: theming, routes

There is a menu plug in called ddmegamenu http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/ddmegamenu.htm

I want to integrate in drupal 7 menu system. I don't know form where to begin
i tried drupal megamenu module, but it is not giving same effect as ddmegamenu.

can anyone guide me how to format menu tree to apply ddmegamenu to my theme..

Answer (score 0):

Dont bother, your basically going to have create module for something like that and someones already done it. This is probably the best mega menu for drupal, just install and away you go. You can add anything you want to the dropdowns, views, blocks, etc.

http://drupal.org/project/om_maximenu

Comment: You are right, but if i want to integrate my own jquery or javascript as per the structure of ddmegamenu(as per above link) then how to create it

Comment: Id just remove the default js file on the fly with something like hook_js_alter(). Take a copy for your theme and make any alterations to that. Then you can leave the module as it is, which ofcourse you should do ;-)